# Returning One Row with Multiple Column Positions as a List

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

My problem seems pretty straight forward, but I'm struggling to grasp an easier way of fulfilling the required output.

**Problem:** I have entries in a table. These entries are identified by an ID column. They are joined with a table that shows a particular volunteer position that they hold or have held. If they are identified as having more than one position, their record returns multiple times.

**Solution:** I would like to list their positions in one column so that their entry based on the ID column returns only once. I have tried using STUFF and CONCAT, but all they return are multiples of the same position held for each entry as opposed to finding out if they have multiple positions and listing them, which means I'm probably using those functions incorrectly.

Here is the current output:

```
ID         FIRST_NAME           current_flag Position
---------- -------------------- ------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
106379     Christine            1            NOMAL
106379     Christine            1            SFC
106418     Mary                 1            CVP
106751     Denise               1            SDFA
106885     Marianna             1            RCRA
107244     Jennifer             1            RCF
```

Here is the desired output:

```
 ID         FIRST_NAME           current_flag Position
---------- -------------------- ------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
106379     Christine            1            NOMAL,SFC
106418     Mary                 1            CVP
106751     Denise               1            SDFA
106885     Marianna             1            RCRA
107244     Jennifer             1            RCF
```

I have removed extraneous columns because the output is not conducive to showing what the desired output would be, but they are included in my code as follows.
Current Code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name.ID, 
                Name.FIRST_NAME, 
                Name.LAST_NAME, 
                Name_Address.ADDRESS_1, 
                Name_Address.CITY, 
                Name_Address.STATE_PROVINCE, 
                Name_Address.ZIP, 
                Name_Address.PREFERRED_MAIL,      
                vcsiboCurrentCommittee.current_flag, 
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Name.BIRTH_DATE, 101) AS BirthDate,
                vcsiboCurrentCommittee.Position
FROM         Name INNER JOIN
             Name_Address ON Name.ID = Name_Address.ID INNER JOIN
             vcsiboCurrentCommittee ON Name.ID = vcsiboCurrentCommittee.ID
WHERE     (Name_Address.PREFERRED_MAIL = 1.00) 
          AND (vcsiboCurrentCommittee.current_flag = 1.00) 
          AND (Name.ID <> 10) AND (Name.BIRTH_DATE <> '') 
          AND (vcsiboCurrentCommittee.CommitteeCode IN 
         ('ALUMNAE_DEPT', 'COLLEGIATE-DEPT', 'EDUCATION', 'FINANCIAL', 'INTERN_COUNCIL', 'IPDEPT', 'MEMBERSHIP','PANHELLENIC', 'REG_1', 'REG_2', 'REG_3', 'REG_4', 'REG_5', 'REG_6', 'REG_7', 'REG_8'))
```

Code using STUFF:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name.ID, 
                Name.FIRST_NAME, 
                Name.LAST_NAME, 
                Name_Address.ADDRESS_1, 
                Name_Address.CITY, 
                Name_Address.STATE_PROVINCE, 
                Name_Address.ZIP,                            
                Name_Address.PREFERRED_MAIL,
                vcsiboCurrentCommittee.current_flag,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Name.BIRTH_DATE, 101) AS BirthDate,
                STUFF(
                (SELECT
                CAST(',' AS varchar(max)) + vcsiboCurrentCommittee.Position
                FROM vcsiboCurrentCommittee AS vcc
                WHERE vcc.ID = Name.ID
                ORDER BY vcc.Position
                FOR xml path('')
                ), 1, 1, '') AS Positions,
            vcsiboCurrentCommittee.Position
FROM Name INNER JOIN
     Name_Address ON Name.ID = Name_Address.ID INNER JOIN
     vcsiboCurrentCommittee ON Name.ID = vcsiboCurrentCommittee.ID
WHERE (Name_Address.PREFERRED_MAIL = 1.00) AND   
      (vcsiboCurrentCommittee.current_flag = 1.00) 
      AND (Name.ID <> 10) AND (Name.BIRTH_DATE <> '') 
      AND (vcsiboCurrentCommittee.CommitteeCode IN ('ALUMNAE_DEPT', 'COLLEGIATE-DEPT', 'EDUCATION', 'FINANCIAL', 'INTERN_COUNCIL', 'IPDEPT', 'MEMBERSHIP', 'PANHELLENIC', 'REG_1', 'REG_2', 'REG_3', 'REG_4', 'REG_5', 'REG_6', 'REG_7', 'REG_8'))
```

That creates this ouput:

```
ID         FIRST_NAME           current_flag Positions                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Position
---------- -------------------- ------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
106379     Christine            1            NOMAL,NOMAL,NOMAL,NOMAL,NOMAL,NOMAL,NOMAL,NOMAL,NOMAL,NOMAL                                                                                                                                                                                                      NOMAL
106379     Christine            1            SFC,SFC,SFC,SFC,SFC,SFC,SFC,SFC,SFC,SFC                                                                                                                                                                                                                          SFC
106418     Mary                 1            CVP,CVP,CVP,CVP,CVP,CVP,CVP,CVP,CVP,CVP,CVP,CVP,CVP                                                                                                                                                                                                              CVP
106751     Denise               1            SDFA,SDFA,SDFA,SDFA,SDFA,SDFA,SDFA,SDFA,SDFA,SDFA,SDFA
```

Thanks in advance.
SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to fix the alias in the subquery and perhaps `select distinct`:

```
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT CAST(',' AS varchar(max)) + vcc.Position
---------------------------------------------------^
        FROM vcsiboCurrentCommittee AS vcc
        WHERE vcc.ID = Name.ID
        ORDER BY vcc.Position
        FOR xml path('')
       ), 1, 1, '') AS Positions,
```

Once you fix the alias (so `Position` refers to the inner table rather than the outer table), then the `DISTINCT` might not be needed.  If you do use `DISTINCT`, the `ORDER BY` might need to be adjusted as well.

EDIT:

The duplicates in the outer query are created by the logic in the outer query.  You probably don't want the same table there as in the subquery.  It is very hard to tell what logic you really want.  Probably some sort of aggregation on `vcsiboCurrentCommittee` before joining it to other tables.

Comment: This is extremely close to the result I was looking for. I did have to remove the 'ORDER BY'. Current result is still showing multiple rows for each entry and they are listing multiple `Positions`. 
Formatting in the comment isn't working - here's a screenshot of the output [http://imgur.com/TgmKcZN]